# ¿Como usar pragma pack?

Tags: c

Me he encontrado recientemente este código

```
#pragma pack(push)
#pragma pack(2)
```

No entiendo muy bien como usar esta directiva de pre procesador aunque por lo que veo esta directamente relacionada con las estructuras

Comment: Si tu pregunta es "¿Cómo usar `pragma pack`?", debes saber que ya lo estas usando. ¿Hay algo que no entiendas exactamente?

Comment: No se a lo que se refiere 'pack' usando pragma en este caso

Comment: Entonces ¿Quieres saber qué es `#pragma pack`?

Comment: Si , cual es su uso en general

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> En resumen: Sirve para alinear los elementos de las estructuras.

---

Es una serie de instrucciones del preprocesador de C que te permiten especificar el alineamiento de las estructuras, por ejemplo:

```
struct Prueba {
  int a; char b;
};
```

Si el tamaño de `int` es 4 y el de `char` es 1, el valor retornado por `sizeof(struct Prueba)` es 8, ¿Por qué? Porque el alineamiento es dependiente del tamaño de la palabra en la arquitectura a la que se compila, por lo que `sizeof(struct Prueba)` puede terminar en 8, o incluso 32 bytes.

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| FF | FF | FF | FF | 00 | Relleno.     |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| Prueba.a;         | .b | Nada         |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Es 8 porque se alinea a los limites de un entero *(`int`)* de 4 bytes, si `Prueba.a` fuera `uint64_t`, entonces `sizeof(struct Prueba)` fuera 16.

`#pragma pack` viene a resolver ese tema<sup>1</sup>:

- `#pragma pack(push)`: Apila en una pila interna el valor anterior para alinear los campos de las estructuras.
- `#pragma pack(push, valor)`: Apila en la pila interna el valor anterior para alinear los campos de las estructuras y a continuación ajusta el nuevo valor para alinear los campos.
- `#pragma pack(N)`: Ajusta el valor para alinear los campos sin más.
- `#pragma pack(pop)`: Ajusta el valor para alinear los campos de las estructuras al último que se utilizó.

Al utilizar `#pragma pack(N)` despues de `#pragma(push)` lo que hacemos es simple, le decimos al compilador:

> ¡Oye! Trata de que todas las estructuras esten alineadas para un minimo de N bytes, pero antes, guarda el valor anterior para restaurarlo luego.

Es decir, algo como...

```
| Alineamiento normal o por defecto     |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| FF | FF | FF | FF | 00 | Relleno.     |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| Prueba.a;         | .b | Nada         |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+

| Con #pragma(2)              |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| FF | FF | FF | FF | 00 | XX |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| Prueba.a;         | .b | -- |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

*Realmente no es tan bonito...*

> **Ventajas de hacer `#pragma pack`**: La esencial es que te ahorras unos cuantos bytes. El principal problema es que la lectura es usualmente lenta, en adición a que al crear un puntero de un elemento dentro de la estructura, no tendríamos un puntero válido<sup>2</sup> *(No del todo cierto, según yo)*.

Código de ejemplo<sup>3</sup>:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  struct Prueba1 {
    int a; char b;
  } A;
  printf("Antes de:\n\t#pragma pack(push)\n\t#pragma pack(2) - ");
  printf("%zu == 8\n", sizeof(struct Prueba1));
  #pragma pack(push)
  #pragma pack(2)
  struct Prueba2 {
    int a; char b;
  } B;
  #pragma pack(pop)
  printf("Luego de:\n\t#pragma pack(push)\n\t#pragma pack(2) - ");
  printf("%zu == 6\n", sizeof(struct Prueba2));
  return 0;
}
```

Imprime respectivamente:

```
Antes de:
    #pragma pack(push)
    #pragma pack(2) - 8 == 8
Luego de:
    #pragma pack(push)
    #pragma pack(2) - 6 == 6
```

---

<sup>1</sup>: Estos `#pragma`s existen para compatibilidad con los compiladores de windows, según GCC. Véase: [Structure-Packing Pragmas](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.4/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html). 
<sup>2</sup>: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14431574/5622844 
<sup>3</sup>: [ideone](https://ideone.com/tH2jOe)